# Building a big table with d3 for IE - performance issue

Tags: internet-explorer, d3.js

I'm building an HTML table using d3. The problem is when the data is big (300 length or so) IE performance is very poor.

After some research I found that it's better (in IE) to build the complete table before I put it in the DOM, but how can I do it with d3?  Is it possible?

I'm kind of new to d3, so maybe I'm using it the wrong way? First I `d3.select('#tableParent')`, then I create the table and `thead` using `d3.append`.

then I apply my data:

```
var rows = myTable.selectAll("tbody").data(data);
var newRows = rows.enter().append("tbody");
```

now I create the row elements using `d3.append`, and update classes and other attributes.

in order to use the data to get text to a column (for example) I'm doing this:

```
myTable.selectAll(".nameColumn").text(function (d, i) { return d.name;})
```

etc...

My table is pretty complex so I'm doing this procedure multiple times.

Maybe I need to iterate on the data and not the columns?

Comment: An example would be helpful - post some source code or make a fiddle. You mentioned building the complete table before adding it to the DOM. This can be done like so:

Comment: var t = document.createElement("table"); d3.select(t).data(data).enter().append("tr")...

Comment: Then when you are done building the table (out of the DOM) you can add it using body.append("table").html(t.outerHTML); (or insert it wherever you want the table to end up)

Answer (score 0):

Check here http://bl.ocks.org/csaladenes/ddc0b326b93ec641c84f

It uses d3 to dynamically build a table and show only once, when done.